# Detecting interlaced H264

Tags: h.264, live555

I'm trying to detect the FPS of H264 (progressive and interlaced) video. I have looked at trying to go off of using field_pic_flag from the SPS but it doesn't seem to be fool proof. I also thought about using the field rate calculated via (time_scale/num_units_in_tick) but that also didn't lead anywhere. Could anyone offer up any other advice? I need to do this without using ffmpeg or any other library. Thanks!

Comment: The field_pic_flag is in the slice header and not in PPS/SPS. You need the PPS/SPS to parse the slice header correctly. I'd put a lot of trust into the slice header. If the slice header is incorrect I'd consider the file incorrectly authored. Please share a file where you code doesn't detect interlacing correctly.