# In H264 How does one identify that interlacing i.e MBAFF is enabled?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, codec

I have some H264 files for which I want to check whether they are MBAFF coded or simply to say whether interlacing is enabled for them or not.

What are the ways or flags one can check to confirm the same?

There is a similar query here [Detecting interlaced H264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320855/detecting-interlaced-h264) but the same is partial and doesn't have a resolution.

Comment: Please provide a sample file and your code that shows what you tried so far.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann cannot share file since all test data is confidential and the code I am using is open source encoder implementation from https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/JM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MBAFF - frame_mbs_only_flag = 0 and mb_adaptive_frame_field_flag = 1
PAFF - frame_mbs_only_flag = 0 and field_pic_flag = 1
```

Also you probably should analyze `pic_struct` from Picture timing SEI

Comment: `pic_struct = read_u_v(4, "SEI: pic_struct" , buf, &p_Dec->UsedBits);` was trying to analyze this in the reference decoder at https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/JM however the above criteria matched but `pic_struct` was never encountered while debugging.